# Two datagrids that share scroll positions, share datasource but do not sync scroll postion

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Hello Stack Overflow,

I have a winforms application that has a two data grid views in the same control that point to the same bindingsource. The purpose of this is to show the column 'customer's name' at all time and allow the rest of the datagrid to be reviewed (scrolled horizontally).

Is there any way i can sync these two up? Currently if the user scrolls vertically down the list of customers, only one datagrid is affected. Do I need to remove scroll bars from one, and cause it to spin both views?

Thanks

Comment: "that point to the same dataset and bindingsource" - a GridView points to a dataset _OR_ a bindingsource

Comment: If the purpose is to keep showing "Customer Name" if user scrolls horizontally...then may be freezing that column is a better idea than using two grids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Scroll event of the first grid and set the scroll offset of the second grid with the value of the first grid scroll

Comment: That worked perfectly Amiram, Thank you very much! Sample of my codes in case anyone wants to see:    
Dim nameVerticalOffset As PropertyInfo = NameDataGridView.GetType().GetProperty("VerticalOffset", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
   nameVerticalOffset.SetValue(NameDataGridView, MainDataGridView.VerticalScrollingOffset, Nothing)

Comment: Why do you need reflection? Isn't the public property VerticalScrollingOffset enough? You can also get the value in the scroll event from the event args

Comment: I like the suggestion of getting the vertical offset from scroll event args, thank you again! however I dont think the datagrid view verticalScrollingOffset has a setter. When i try to set the property by doing something like "NameDataGridView.VerticalScrollingOffset = MainDataGridView.VerticalScrollingOffset" i get the readonly error.

Comment: Didn't notice that. HorizontalScrollingOffset has a set but VerticalScrollingOffset doesn't! You can also use FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex if you have the same rows.